# Multiple gradle plugin in use which keeps me from building my APK file

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, gradle, gradlew

I'm trying to build an android APK and but it tells me multiple versions of the plugin is in use. How do solve this?

[image]

I've been trying to use gradlew to exclude the pulled library as i saw someone mention it in another thread but I haven't grasped how it works.

All help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

**Backup** your project and try to **downgrade** to Unity version **2018.4.3f1**

Comment: downgrading solved it, but unity 2019.4.18f1 worked

Comment: good for you! 2019 versions are good and stable too